# tufte handout document class not recognized when compiled in Emacs

Tags: xetex, emacs, auctex, tufte

I don't understand why tufte handout is not recognized when I compile it in Emacs. The standard tex engine there is xetex. I understand that this might be the key problem but I was unable to figure out how to change that to xelatex. For instance, I can flawlessly compile the file correctly via pdflatex command but when I am using the AUCTeX/Emacs one it doesn't work.

What I tried was the classic <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> trick; and the output that I received was a pdf that wasn't formatted well.

Additionally, an extract from the cat `sample.log` revealed the following error messages:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdftex 2017.1.28)  4 FEB 2017 08:37entering extended moderestricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input sample-notes-2.tex
(./sample-notes-2.tex
./sample-notes-2.tex:1: Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {tufte-handout}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

etc...

```
    ### simple group (level 2) entered at line 27 ({)
    ### simple group (level 1) entered at line 27 ({)
    ### bottom level</usr/share/texlive/texmf-          
    dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
    mmi10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-     
    dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.p
    fb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-   
    dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
    Output written on sample-notes-2.pdf (1 page, 35223 bytes).
    PDF statistics:
   26 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
   13 compressed objects within 1 object stream
   0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
   1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

So essentially I did get an  output one page pdf but the content was a complete mess.

Comment: Does it help if you add the following 5 lines at the end of your file, restart Emacs and open your file again?  `%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: xetex 
%%% End:`

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt help at all. you probably mean after \end{document}. But that would not necessarily make also sense to me.

Comment: Yes, I meant after `\end{document}` in 5 separate lines.  In your .tex file, what do you see in echo area if you put this `(executable-find "xelatex")` somewhere, move point after `)` and hit `C-x C-e`?

Comment: symbol's value as variable is void:error. That is if I understood correctly.

Comment: You get that result with `(executable-find "xelatex")*` where `*` was the cursor as you hit `C-x C-e`?  Hmm, if Emacs doesn't find the binary, you should check the way environment variable `PATH` is set.  It seems to be different in the prompt where you did it with `pdflatex`.  You can check the `PATH` in Emacs with `C-h v exec-path RET`.

Answer (score 1):

`\documentclass` is defined for the LaTeX format.  You're trying to process the LaTeX format with XeTeX.  Use XeLaTeX instead:

```
M-x LaTeX-mode RET  ;; my guess is you mistakenly used 'TeX-mode' here
M-x TeX-engine-set RET xetex RET
```

Your compilation buffer should look something like this:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `temp-file--65261vvi' with ``xelatex  -file-line-error   -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" temp-file--65261vvi.tex''
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(./temp-file--65261vvi.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(./temp-file--65261vvi.aux) [1] (./temp-file--65261vvi.aux) )
Output written on temp-file--65261vvi.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on temp-file--65261vvi.log.

TeX Output finished at Sat Mar  4 22:21:18
```